# Auth guard [api] is not defined

Tags: laravel, authentication, base64, intervention

I checked several questions with the same error above I mentioned. But couldn't find the answer.
I'm trying to turn my base64 string into an image file.
Here is the code in my controller,

```
public function createImage(Request $request)
    {
      $user = auth('api')->user();
      if($request->photo){
         $name = time().'.'. explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->photo, 0, strpos
         ($request->photo, ';')))[1])[1];
         \Image::make($request->photo)->save(public_path('public/').$name);
        }
    }
```

When executing this using base64 encoded string via Postman below error appears:

```
"message": "Auth guard [api] is not defined.",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\konekt\\testmyusers-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php",
```

I don't know if my controller code is right or not. I used a youtube video as the source. Can I do it this way or should I change my method?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added guard `api` in `config/auth.php`.
If not added then please add below guard with driver and provider details in `config/auth.php`.

```
'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My team had a lot of similar issues using the Passport library for API, so if you're using that, and don't need Passport's level of complexity of OAuth, I would recommend looking into [Sanctum](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum)